# Is it possible to rotate a 360 deg image mapped onto a sphere around an axis?

Tags: imagemagick, scikit-image, polar-coordinates

There's an [example](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polar) in `imagemagick` tutorial, which demonstrates how to transform equirectangular 360 degree panorama into a polar view by using `convert` tool.
The resulting image is a somewhat distorted view of a sphere, as viewed from either of its poles.

What I am be interested with would be if it is possible to apply additional transformation which would result in having a polar view image, but as if the 'sphere' was rotated around an axis which goes through the equator. Center of the image would then not show artctic nor Antarctic region, but for instance Berlin or California.

Is this possible with `imagemagick`, `scikit-image`, or other open source tool?

**EDIT**

Example:

Initial picture:

[image]

Transformed picture, focused on the polar region:

[image]

Desired transformed picture, focused on Europe:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have and what you want?

Comment: @fmw42 I've edited my question with example images.

Comment: -distort polar is not a spherical mapping and so cannot be centered anywhere. You can move the center point horizontally with no issue, which will just rotate the result. But you cannot move the center point vertically without getting a weird result that does not correspond to a spherical mapping. Anything at the center point will be treated as if at the pole and compressed accordingly.

Comment: You can try shifting the image (-roll horizontally and shift vertically) to center where you want. Then use my spherize script at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/.  But I am still not sure if that would work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best that I can do with 2D image processing with Imagemagick rather than a proper 3D projection.

To move the viewpoint, roll the image in x and shift it in y. Then use my spherize script at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick

Input:

[image]

Spherize of input:

```
spherize -s worldmap_sm.jpg worldmap_sm_sphere.jpg
```

[image]

Process for other viewpoint:

convert worldmap_sm.jpg -roll +64+0 -define
distort:viewport=256x160+0-32 -virtual-pixel background -background
red -filter point -distort SRT 0 +repage worldmap_sm_usa.png

spherize -s worldmap_sm_usa.png worldmap_sm_usa_sphere.jpg

[image]

With my spherize script and the roll and shift, there are areas that will be missing, which I coded in red. This will only occur due to the vertical shift and not with the horizontal roll.  (Rolling vertically would have wrapped the South Pole next to the North Pole)

Comment: Thank you @fmw42 for your effort, but for the regions very close to the polar region the distorions are too big for what I need this for.